# AWS manual Snapshot shared with other accounts slows down database and API

Tags: amazon-web-services, entity-framework, encryption, mariadb, amazon-rds

I am dumping data from a production account into a QA account. I made a manual snapshot of an encrypted database, made a new encrypted snapshot that is shared between accounts (gave privileges to the KMS key to the QA account, a symmetric key). I made the corresponding snapshot of the shared one in the QA account and restored it to a new DB instance.

The problem I am having is that the data from the production environment is slowing down the QA environment by an unreasonable amount. The QA API gets pinned at 99% CPU usage and the number of connections on the QA database only keeps growing. What might be the root cause of the issue?

There is a size instance difference between the accounts (i.e small vs micro instances) but nothing to warrant such a spike. Using an older snapshot does not produce the same issue.

Other info.
Database: MariaDb 10.2
API : .Net 4.6 EntityFramework.

Comment: `API gets pinned at 99% CPU` you mean the RDS data API or some application? During restore or always? If it's the api/app side, what it has to do with the backup or rds? You need to provide more detailed profiling information what us taking the cpu and why. What queries is the app doing? Over what data/indexes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by a loose AWS lambda hitting the QA API, trying to process an unreasonable amount of data at the same time leading to a CPU bottleneck.